# Using UserControl as base class in wpf is showing empty

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, prism

Hello I am using Prism in my demo project and I have a problem with user controls' inheritance. If I use my user control base class for my user control like below, user control's content is showing up empty. Then when I use

```
<igf:UserControlBase x:Class="DemoProject.Views.DemoView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:igf="http://igf.schema"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="300" d:DesignHeight="200">
             <StackPanel>
                 <TextBox Text="Hello Prism"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="Hello Prism"></TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
</igf:ViewControlBase>
```

and this is my user control and it is in another project. And ctors are commented now but still not working. Only way is changing

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DemoProject.Base.Controls
{
    public class UserControlBase : UserControl
    {
        static UserControlBase()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UserControlBase), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UserControlBase)));
        }

        public UserControlBase()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(UserControlBase);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you defined regions ? Could you please post code of the Shell. And how do you register your view with the region ? How are you navigating. Please provide code of ViewModels as well.

Comment: Shell is like generally used format in best practises. Registering is done by Unity and IRegionManager. I can post the code but I cant understand why just UserControl shows the content? If I use just UserControl as base class everything is normal. Even design mode is empty.

Comment: Set Debug->Exceptions for CLR Exceptions in Thrown and track if there are some messages in the output console. I think there is an exception which is swallowed by prism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by adding code below into Assembly.cs file to user control's project

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly)]
```